# ajax performs actions based on Json object sent from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-deployment

I am learning Ajax now and not sure if Ajax can handle my use case.
I have a template (a JSP file in Spring MVC) which has a button.
My current design is that if a user clicks on the button, he/she will be redirected to another page

```
        $('#Button').on('click',function() {
      location.href = "/fulfill/order/${orderID}";
    });
```

Now, I want to redesign my controller `/fulfill/order/${orderID}` to return Json object. 
So if a user clicks on the button now, the controller still will be called and returns Json object. So Ajax can catch those Json object and perform actions based on the Json object sent by this controller.
For example, if a user clicks on the button, the controller returns the Json object "successful" and Ajax process this Json object and  displays an image; if the controller returns the Json object "error, can not fulfill", Ajax processes this Json object and shows a pop-up error message.

How could I use Ajax to do this task. Is that possible?

Comment: _"the controller returns the Json object "successful""_ `"successful"` appears to be string. Are you trying to return string "successful" and `JSON` as response? Is `"successful"` a property name of `JSON`?

Comment: @guest271314 I did some research and it seems that ResponseEntity makes more sense than Json object in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get("/fulfill/order/${orderID}",{},function(response){
     console.log(response);

})
```

If your controller's action accepts only  POST request :

```
$.post("/fulfill/order/${orderID}",{},function(response){
     console.log(response);

}) ;
```

If you want to pass further parameters (i.e : `"/fulfill/order/${orderID}"?id=4343&before=2016`) , you will need to replace the 2n argument `{}` by `{id:4343,before:2016}`

---

`$.get` & `$.post` come to simplify `$.ajax` call . However, it is recommended to use `$.ajax` instead , if you want to set custom parameters of your AJAX Call :

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/fulfill/order/${orderID}",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

#### A good tuto [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/) that handles many use-cases of Spring MVC+AJAX

Comment: May you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602467/ajax-performs-actions-based-on-responseentity-sent-by-controllers